# Should a Marionette CollectionView be used without a Backbone Collection?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Although the [Marionette Wiki](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/Use-cases-for-the-different-views) states that:

> A collection view is used for rendering a Backbone.Collection, and a view instance for each item in the collection.

It's possible to use it for other purposes such as rendering a set of ItemViews, which we know [can be used without a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674770/using-marionette-itemview-for-views-without-models).

Case in point is a navigation menu where each link is an ItemView that does not trigger a route change but issues events that layouts can listen on in order to show their regions.

Is it considered bad practice or incorrect to use a CollectionView which is not ultimately associated with a model resource and unlikely to need to re-render?

Comment: Is it considered bad practice or incorrect to use a CollectionView which is not ultimately associated with a resource model and unlikely to need to re-render?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it considered bad practice or incorrect to use a CollectionView which is not ultimately associated with a model resource and unlikely to need to re-render?

No, that's not bad practice or incorrect use. It's just re-purposing it and customizing it - nothing wrong with that.

The default behavior is to render a Backbone.Collection, but this can be changed however you need, to render whatever collection of things for your scenario. I've seen people change the `serializeData` method to render an array, for example.

What you need to watch out for, though, is adding more complexity to the CollectionView than it's worth. It may be a better use of your time to build your own view types that handle exactly the scenario you need, rather than try to re-purpose CollectionView for this. I'm not saying that this is the case for you, right now, though. Just a caution of complexity to watch out for.

Comment: Derick, what if, in a CollectionView, you want to pass dynamic data into each child ItemView at runtime? Typically, if your CollectionView were associated with an actual Backbone Collection, you'd use the model passed to itemViewOptions to return this dynamic data. But if you are not using a Backbone Collection, there's no argument passed (such as an index) to differentiate one call to ItemViewOptions from another. Is there a convention in Marionette for solving this problem?

Comment: you can provide an `itemViewOptions` hash or function, that gets mixed in to the `options` parameter provided to the itemView instance

Comment: Suppose a CollectionView has a `names` array, and wants to pass each child ItemView a single value from this array. When ItemViewOptions is called, how would the parent collection know which entry in `names` to pass to the ItemView? Would it have to maintain an internal counter of the number of times ItemViewOptions was called, and return values from the `names` property accordingly? ie: this.names[this.counter]?

Comment: Maybe through [Backbone.ChildViewContainer](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.babysitter#storing-views)?

Comment: Yes, the ChildViewContainer from Backbone.BabySitter would be a great place to start, for building your view's needs. You can probably borrow a lot of code from Marionette.CollectionView while your at it. I would love to see your result - perhaps a Marionette add-on :) A lot of people ask have asked for a similar thing.

Comment: Sure thing. Would love to get your opinion in general on what we're doing at CrowdTwist sometime.